# How do I retrieve a list of class variables from an instance of that class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables

As an example, here is the following class:

```
class Fruits(object):
    
    name = 'Fruits'
    short_description = 'Fruits class'
    long_description = 'Fruits class that takes in a list of fruits'
    
    def __init__(self,fruits_lst):
        
        self.fruits_lst = fruits_lst
        self.total = len(fruits_lst)
```

I want to retrieve a list of the class variables, not including any class instance variables.  That is the list would be ['name','short_description','long_description'].

How do I do this?

I recoginise that I can deploy this to pull out information on the class:

```
fruits = Fruits(['Apples','Bananas','Oranges'])

dir(fruits)

['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'fruits_lst',
 'long_description',
 'name',
 'short_description',
 'total']
```

but, how might I pull out just the information that I want?

Thank you!

Update:

I have just figured out that I can do this by applying dir to the class itself rather than the instance of the class:

```
class_variables = [var for var in dir(Fruits) if not var.startswith('__')]
class_variables

['long_description', 'name', 'short_description']
```

So, this is a "solution".  However, for the use case that I have, I only have access to the class instance, rather than the class itself.  So, is there a way to pull this information out via the class instance and perhaps directly rather than having to filter via a list comprehension?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

still looks hacky, but:

```
[i for i in vars(Fruits).keys() if not i.startswith('__')]
# in case of instance
[i for i in vars(fruits.__class__).keys() if not i.startswith('__')]
```

at least less values to filter

**updated**

to prevent getting class method names in the list

```
attribute_list = []
for k, v in vars(Fruits).items():
    if not k.startswith('__') and not callable(v):
            attribute_list.append(k)
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful.  Although, if there were a function defined within the class (not starting with '__' as the init does) in the example, this would seem to also return the name of that function within the list.  So an issue with this approach, given that it is just the class variables that I am looking to return.

Comment: Instead of using list+filter with a lambda, just use a list comp(which looks cleaner IMO)

Comment: `and not hasattr(v, '__call__')` -> `not callable(v)`

Comment: @agftrading **the function is a class variable**

Comment: @agftrading Updated my answer. Now it excludes also methods

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so, is there a different term that I should be using that refers to the variables as per my example and not the functions then?

Comment: @SuperStomer, @ juanpa.arrivillaga you're right! I've correct the answer

Comment: @agftrading there is no specific term. Those are all just class variables. You are interested in particular ones. You could say "class variables not including methods"